# About $\mathring{\overbrace{]-4, 0]\cup\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \geq1 \right\} }}$

Tags: general-topology

My question about the interior of $S=]-4, 0]\cup\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n \geq1  \right\} $

Let $S_1=]-4, 0]$, $S_2=\left\{ \frac{1}{n}: n\geq1  \right\}$

We have $\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}=]-4, 0[\cup \emptyset$

Since we have $\operatorname{Bd}(S_1)\cap\operatorname{Bd}(S_2)=\{0\}$

So we have $\mathring{S}=\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}\neq\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$

How can I find $\mathring{S}$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use titles that are entirely MathJax.

Comment: Why do you claim that $\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}\ne\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$?

Comment: Hint: $\mathring{S}$ is the largest open set contained in $S$. Every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is countable union of open intervals.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}\neq\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$ because $\operatorname{Bd}(S_1)\cap\operatorname{Bd}(S_2)=\{0\}$ where $\operatorname{Bd}(S_1)$ is Boundary of $S_1$

Comment: How is that relevant? The interior of $S_1\cup S_2$ is $(-4,0)$, which is the union of the interior of $S_1$ ($(-4,0)$) with the interior of $S_2$ ($\emptyset$).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I didn't understand how to calculate The interior of $S_1\cup S_2$? if we have $\operatorname{Bd}(S_1)\cap\operatorname{Bd}(S_2)=\{0\}$  we can use $\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$

Comment: What do you mean by “we can use”? Are you saying now that the interior of $S_1\cup S_2$ is $\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, if $\operatorname{Bd}(S_1)\cap\operatorname{Bd}(S_2)=\{0\}$, we have  $\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}=\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$.

Comment: Indeed. But in your question you wrote that $\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}\ne\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, But I mean if  $\operatorname{Bd}(S_1)\cap\operatorname{Bd}(S_2)=\emptyset$ we have $\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}=\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$ but in this example we have $\operatorname{Bd}(S_1)\cap\operatorname{Bd}(S_2)=\{0\}$, So we have $\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}\ne\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}$.

Comment: How can those sets be different when both of them are equal to $(-4,0)$? Or are you claiming that one of those sets is not $(-4,0)$? If so, which one?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $\mathring{S_1}\cup\mathring{S_2}=]-4, 0[\cup \emptyset=]-4, 0[$ But How can I find $\mathring{\overbrace{S_1\cup S_2}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(-4,0)\subset S$ and it is an open set. Therefore, $(-4,0)\subset\mathring S$.

Now, let $x\in S\setminus(-4,0)$. Then $x=0$ or $x=\frac1n$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$. But $0\notin\mathring S$, because any neighborhood $V$ of $0$ contains some interval $(0,\varepsilon)$ and this interval has numbers $y$ which are not of the form $\frac1n$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$. But then $y\in V\setminus S$, and therefore $V\not\subset S$. So, $0\notin\mathring S$. And if $x=\frac1n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then take $W=\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n-1}\right)$ (if $n>1$) or $V=\left(\frac12,\infty\right)$ (if $n=1$). Then $W$ is a neighborhood of $\frac1n$, but $\frac1n$ is the only element of $S\cap W$. So, if $V$ is *any* neighborhood of $\frac1n$, then $W\cap V$ is a neighborhood of $\frac1n$ which is not a subset of $S$. So, $\frac1n\notin\mathring S$.

So, $(-4,0)=\mathring S$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @BrianTung I've edited my answer. Thank you.